# delphi arrayWithObject makes the Mac asleep

Tags: macos, delphi

Delphi XE4 update1, desktop application with target platform MAC OS.

I try to register a font in font collection. Here is my code:

```
ns:=NSSTR(myCollection);
fManager.addCollection(ns,0);
fontDesc:= TNSFontDescriptor.Wrap(TNSFontDescriptor.OCClass.fontDescriptorWithName(
  NSSTR(fontName+'-'+weightName), 10.0));

a1:=TNSArray.Wrap(TNSArray.OCClass.arrayWithObject(@fontDesc)); //here the computer falls asleep
fManager.addFontDescriptors(a1,ns);
```

I am not familiar with all this OS X stuff. Please help.

Edit: Here is the working code:

```
fontURL:=CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR(srcPath + fileName + ext), kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false);
fManager := TNsFontManager.Wrap(TNsFontManager.OCClass.sharedFontManager);
ns:=NSSTR(myCollection);
cf:=CTFontManagerCreateFontDescriptorsFromURL(fontURL);
a1 := TNSArray.Create;
TNSArray.Init(a1,cf);
fManager.addFontDescriptors(a1,ns);
```

Comment: Are you quite sure that `@fontDesc` is the right thing to use?

Comment: What do you mean by 'asleep'?

Comment: The cursor is rolling wheel and nothing happens until I use Force Quit.

Comment: @David: Just tried with a1:=TNSArray.Wrap(TNSArray.OCClass.arrayWithObject(TNSFontDescriptor.OCClass.fontDescriptorWithName(NSSTR(fontName+'-'+weightName), 10.0))); and it passes, but in the collection there is no font.

Comment: Looks like you are using trial and error here. What is expected to be passed to `arrayWithObject`? What is `@fontDesc`? Is it the right thing?

Comment: David, thanks. Made it, by using CTFontManagerCreateFontDescriptorsFromURL to get the CFArrayRef and then TNSArray.Init to convert to NSArray. Mac Development library looks pretty odd for me. Maybe there is better and shorter way, but that's what I did.